# set Contact tab default instead of Home tab when login into dev or sandbox

Tags: tab

whenever login from sales-force home tab show (open by default). I want to set contact tab by default when login into sales-force.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can change default tab by app level. You need to go and edit apps which you need contact as default tab. Go to **Setup** > **Create** > **Apps**. Choose app do you need to modify. Select contacts as default landing tab and enable profiles which need this setting.
[image]